# How to retrieve last week via YEARWEEK in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

What is the syntax in MySQL 5.7 to select a yearweek before a given one?

I know that this works with date() but I have the yearweek saved and need to get data that is e.g. one week prior?

Example:

```
select 202101 - interval 1 week
```

Expected:

```
202053
```

Answer (score 0):

First you must convert `'202101'` to a date (the `Sunday` of that week) with `STR_TO_DATE`, subtract 1 week and then get the week:

```
SELECT YEARWEEK(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('202101',' Sunday'), '%X%V %W') - INTERVAL 1 week, 6) AS week;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=73566846b014c1caafdb10fa16002ce1).
Result:

```
week
-----
202053
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. For me that seems only to work for exactly that example but it does not work for e.g.  202053 and also at least dbfiddle run fails on 5.7

Comment: @merlin the problem with the week numbers is the starting day of the week. I used Sunday, this is why I placed 6 as the 2nd argument of YEARWEEK(). If I remove 6, then the starting day is considered to be Monday and the result is `202052` and not `202053` which you expect: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b6caa08c456ff05c7fdaf1ed235fdb42

Comment: I understand, but I believe there is something else wrong. I tried also other yearweeks in the past and the result on mysql 5.7 is always the same as the given yearweek.